# PHP mail() using a variable

Tags: php, email, variables

I am using a script in PHP that will allow me to send email, the one [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). I also have some variables that receive data from a text box, but I know that is not the problem, since I have seen it work. Anyway, my question is this: how would I set the recipient to a variable? I have tried the obvious and it hasn't worked. It says the email is sent, but I don't receive it :S. Any thoughts on this? Thanks,
Joey

Comment: `$to = "email@address.com";` post your code for a better answer...

Comment: @Paul thanks, but that's not a variable. I need something like `$email = "*My value here*"; $to = $email`

Comment: see below for an answer.

Comment: Learning PHP would help. In particular, I think what you're asking is how to get the email address from a form?  You will want to look into $_POST.

Comment: When you say "set the recipient to a variable," are you referring to some previously-defined pseudo-constant, or to a form value?

Comment: @Corbin Reading the post would help. No, I said I got the $_POST working, it just wouldn't send if I used a variable.

Comment: @user1302302 - Chill out. Your question is VERY unclear. People are trying to help, but you're not making is easy

Comment: @Tieson Previously-defined pseudo-constant.

Comment: @Paul Well, how could I make it more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use this example from the same source example 3

```
     <?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: LOL I can't beleive I missed that! Thx tho.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$email = "email@address.com";
$to = $email;
```